# Testing an IR receiver

Tags: linux, hardware

I have a QNAP TS-453 (I assume it's proprietary Linux etc) and a RM-IR001 IR remote. This remote worked with my old QNAP and now I can't get it to work.

I did the iPhone trick and can see that the remote is 'working' (you can see the remote diode flashing with the iPhone camera).

I am assuming there would be some sort of command line option to monitor the IR input directly and confirm it is actually working before moving on to the next suspect (Kodi). I have no idea where to start.

Comment: From my experience finding the IR receiver on a WDTV you have to search. A lot. Get a root shell, start identifying hardware. The prime suspect is a Super I/O chip, if present. Unless someone happens to have exactly the same system and has already found, it's not an easy task. Also read up on IR remote protocols, there's a number of different ones.